# How to include quoted text in-line?

Tags: feature-request, markdown

I understand that `>` can be used to create blocks of quoted text, but is there a way to format a small quoted phrase within a paragraph of my answer, like the backtick does for code formatting?

If not, could that be added?

If this already exists, I apologize that I was not able to discover it.

Comment: Hm, what would this formatting look like, exactly?

Comment: I usually just use italics for inline quotes. It works well enough.

Comment: What's wrong with using the backticks? Works for me.

Comment: @Straitjacket I find that a monospaced quote like `What's wrong with using the backticks?` doesn't look right. If it makes sense to have a different formats for code blocks and quote blocks, it seems sensible to have different formats for in-line code or quote snippets.

Comment: @hammar Good point, I'll do that, unless someone informs me that this feature already exists.

Comment: The problem is that something like this doesn't exist in Markdown, and I don't think SE wants to deviate from the "official" flavor too much.

Comment: Might be easy **>** to come up with a rational in-line markup **<** for quoted text that would be simple to parse out by any state machine.